Animated horse movie/series 1980s-early 1990s, hunted by mad scientist with robot dog
Looking to identify an animated movie I saw in the US in about 1995 probably on VHS (or less likely perhaps an episode of a TV series of which I have never seen another episode). 
Plot: 
Features horses who live in the wild and are hunted by a mad scientist in a mountain lair. He hates horses and plans turn them into dog food. The horses have to evade his traps and I think at the end they foil his plans. 
Particular elements that may be useful in finding this film:

Animated, color, animation style seemed American
I likely rented it in about 1995 on VHS. Video store had lots of 1980's era animated movies so could be from that era
Vividly remember a few key elements:

There are two remote-controlled grey robot dogs (think: bulldog). One is small and is like a pet to the mad scientist. One is huge and scoops up the trapped horses in his mouth to bring them back to the lair (maybe 10 at a time).
The horses are trapped variously in nets and pits
The scientist wears a lab coat and is short and stout. He may be a child. I think he had a bad experience
Inside of the mountain lair contains a machine he plans to use to turn the horses into dog food. I think the horses are freed from a giant holding net inside the mountain before he can use it.


Other points that may help:

Early on the horses are trying to figure out why their friends are disappearing
Horses seem to live in a forest habitat
Horses are various different colors, but I believe all natural
I do not remember any names, or if the horses were referred to as horses, ponies, brumbies, mustangs etc.

I have searched long and hard for this movie. My sister also remembers it but neither of us has found a lead. Now turning it over to the community. Thanks in advance!

It could be The Silver Brumby.
The series focuses on Thowra, a silver colt, his brothers Storm and Arrow and their friends the bush animals in their continued quest to resist the Men's efforts to capture them.
Original release:   29 October 1994 – 17 September 1998

I am very convinced about the plot of the mad scientist and robot dogs, which as far as I have seen was never a Silver Brumby episode and outside of its setting.

Oh, ok. It was a long shot any way.
